# Using buttons to search through an sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing an android application that takes user information entered in an edit text as an argument in an sql argument. An example of this is if I were to type in "Business A" and click one of my buttons that says "By Name" it would search the database using the Name column and display the results.  The other button is "By Type" which would essentially do the same thing but only by the type of business. My code runs without errors on an emulator and displays my background image, the buttons, and the text. Upon clicking it'll say what it's searching by but is not actually searching anything.  I am new to android programming and any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. I have put my code below for others to view.

Main activity where the database is created:

```
package com.example.database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUSINESS = "business";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BloomBusiness";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Business";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table Business (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "business text not null, address text not null, phone text not null,hours text not null,website text not null,type text not null" 
        + ")";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public MainActivity(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            try{
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Business");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public MainActivity open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertTitle(String business, String address, String phone, String hours, String website, String type) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_HOURS, hours);
        initialValues.put(KEY_WEB, hours);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_BUSINESS,
                KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_PHONE,
                KEY_HOURS,
                KEY_WEB,
                KEY_TYPE}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_BUSINESS, 
                        KEY_ADDRESS,
                        KEY_PHONE,
                        KEY_HOURS,
                        KEY_WEB,
                        KEY_TYPE
                        }, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String business, 
    String address, String phone, String hours, String website, String type) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        args.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        args.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        args.put(KEY_HOURS,hours);
        args.put(KEY_WEB,website);
        args.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }


}
```

Where the data should hopefully be displayed:

```
package com.example.database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;



public class DBUse extends Activity {

    EditText dEdit;
    Button  type;
    Button name;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static String logtag="Buttons";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity db = new MainActivity(this);

        Button buttonName =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonName);
        buttonName.setOnClickListener(startName);

        Button buttonType =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
        buttonType.setOnClickListener(startType);

        dEdit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        db.open();


        Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{DisplayTitle(c);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }   
        db.open();
        Cursor b = db.getAllTitles();

        if (b.moveToFirst())
            DisplayTitle(b);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"No business found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();

    db.close();


}



//displays the data

    public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
        "Name: " + c.getString(1)+"\n"+
        "Address:" + c.getString(2)+"\n"+
        "Phone:" + c.getString(3)+"\n"+
        "Hours:" + c.getString(4)+"\n"+
        "Website"+ c.getShort(5)+
        "Type" + c.getShort(6),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }




private OnClickListener startName=new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick (View v){
        Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where name like %"+dEdit.getText().toString()+"%", null);
        String result="";

        int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
        int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
        int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
        int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
        int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
        int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
        Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
        for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
            result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";

        }
        return;
    }

};
    //Informs the user what is being searched
private OnClickListener startType=new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick (View v){
        Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where type like %"+dEdit.getText().toString()+"%", null);
        String result="";
        int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
        int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
        int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
        int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
        int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
        int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
        //Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
        for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
            result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";


        }
        return;
}
};
}
```

Lastly where all the data is coming from.

```
package com.example.database;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import static android.provider.BaseColumns._ID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class DBActivity extends Activity {
    MainActivity eventsData;
    EditText output;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity db= new MainActivity(this);

        output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        //type.setOnClickListener(
        //      new OnClickListener(){
        //          public void onClick(View view){
        //              Log.v("Entry",dEdit.getText().toString());
            //      }
        ///     });


        //try{String destPath="/data/data" +getPackageName()+ "/databases/BloomBusiness";
        //  File f = new File(destPath);
        //  if(!f.exists()){
        //      CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("db"), new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        //  }
        //  
        //  
        //}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        //}catch(IOException e){
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        //}

        db.open();

        //inserting all data
        long id; 
        id =db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","419 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-Sat:8AM-9PM Sun:9AM-8PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");


        id=db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","316 W. 6th Street Bloomington, IN", "812-333-5300", "M-Sat:7AM-10PM Sun:9AM-9PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");
        id=db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","3220 E. 3rd Street Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-Sun:8AM-10PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Uptown Cafe","102 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-0900", "M-Sat:8AM-9PM Sun:9AM-8PM", "http://www.the-uptown.com/","Cajun-Creole");
        id=db.insertTitle("Crazy Horse","214 W. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-8877", "M-Sat:11AM-2AM Sun:Noon-Midnight", "http://www.crazyhorseindiana.com/","Restaurant & Live Music");
        id=db.insertTitle("FARMbloomington","108 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-0002", "Tue.-Thurs.:8AM-10PM F:8AM-1AM Sat: 10AM-3AM Sun: 10AM-10PM","http://www.farm-bloomington.com","Grocery");
        id=db.insertTitle("Laughing Planet","322 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-2233", "M-Sun:11AM-9PM","http://www.facebook.com/laughingplanetbtown","Burritos & Salads");
        id=db.insertTitle("Soma Coffeehouse","322 E. Kirkwood Bloomington, IN", "812-331-2770", "M-Sat:7AM-11PM Sun:8AM-11PM","http://www.iheartsoma.com","Coffee House");
        id=db.insertTitle("Upland Brewing Company","350 W. 11th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-2337", "M-Thurs:11AM-Midnight F-Sat:11AM-1AM Sun: Noon-Midnight","http://www.uplandbeer.com","Brewery & Restaraunt");
        id=db.insertTitle("Nick's English Hut","423 E. Kirkwood Bloomington, IN", "812-332-4040", "M-Sat:11AM-2AM Sun: Noon-Midnight","http://www.nicksenglishhut.com","Bar & Restaraunt");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Village Deli","409 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-2303", "M-F:7AM-8PM Sat-Sun 8AM-8PM","http://www.villagedeli.biz","Breakfast,Lunch,Dinner");
        id=db.insertTitle("Rachael's Cafe","300 E. 3rd St. Bloomington, IN", "812-330-1882", "M-F:8AM-9PM Sat-Sun 9AM-9PM","http://www.rachaelscafe.com","Coffee House & Live Music");
        id=db.insertTitle("Happy Pig","1604 W. 7th St. Bloomington, IN", "None", "W:Sample Gates Noon-3PM Thurs:Sample Gates Noon-3PM F:Atlas Bar 11:30PM-3:30AM Sat:Courthouse Square 11:30PM-3:30AM","http://www.happypigbloomington.com","BBQ Streetfood");
        id=db.insertTitle("Lennie's Restaurant and Brewpub","1795 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-2112", "Sun-Th:11AM-11PM F-Sat 11AM-Midnight","http://www.lenniesgourmetpizza.com","Bar & Restaurant");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","1791 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-7737", "Sun-Tues:11AM-2AM Wed-Thur: 11AM-3AM F-Sat:11AM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","1610 W. 3rd St. Bloomington, IN", "812-332-2522", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","877 S. College Mall Rd. Bloomington, IN", "812-355-5000", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","2443 S. Walnut St. Pk. Bloomington, IN", "812-332-8500", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Atlas Bar","209 S. College Ave.  Bloomington, IN", "812-334-4435", "M-F:5PM-3AM Sat-Sun:7PM-3AM","http://www.atlasballroom.com","Bar");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Bishop","123 S. Walnut St.  Bloomington, IN", "812-333-4700", "Mon-Sat:7PM-3AM","http://www.thebishopbar.com","Bar & Live Music");
        id=db.insertTitle("Oliver Winery","8024 N. State Road 37 Bloomington, IN", "812-876-5800", "Mon-Sat:10AM-6PM Sun: 12PM-6PM Tours:F-Sat Noon-4:30PM Sun:1PM-4:30PM","http://www.oliverwinery.com","Winery");
        id=db.insertTitle("Revolution Bike and Bean","401 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-0241", "Mon-Fri:10AM-6PM Sat: 10AM-5PM","http://www.revolutionbikeandbean.com","Coffee House & Bike Repair Shop");
        id=db.insertTitle("Mother Hubbard's Cupboard","1010 S. Walnut Bloomington, IN", "812-355-6843", "Mon-Fri:4PM-6PM","http://www.mhcfoodpantry.org","Food Pantry Service & Non-Profit");
        id=db.insertTitle("Patricia's Wellness Arts Cafe and Quilter's Comfort Teas","725 W. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-331-0886", "Mon-Sat:11AM-5PM First Friday: 11AM-8PM","http://www.hartrock.net/cafe.htm","Tea House & Holistic and Naturopathic & Reiki & Counseling");
        id=db.insertTitle("One World Catering and Events","2234 W. Industrial Pk. Dr. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-3663", "","http://www.oneworldcateringandevents.com","Catering");
        id=db.insertTitle("Nelson's Furniture Restoration","6573 S. Old State Road 37 Bloomington, IN", "812-824-7769", "M-F:10AM-6PM","http://www.nelsonrestoration.com","Furniture Restoration");
        id=db.insertTitle("NR Hiller Design, Inc","3450 S. Garrison Chapel. Rd. Bloomington, IN", "812-825-5872", "Hours By Appointment","http://www.nrhillerdesign.com","Furniture Design & Furniture Building & Cabinet-Making & Furniture");
        id=db.insertTitle("Showers Inn Bed and Breakfast","430 N. Washington St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-9000", "Hours By Appointment","http://www.showersinn.com","Bed and Breakfast");
        id=db.insertTitle("Monroe County History Center","202 E. 6th St.  Bloomington, IN", "812-332-2517", "Tues-Sat:10AM-4PM","http://www.monroehistory.org","Museum");
        id=db.insertTitle("WFHB","108 W. 4th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-0320", "Hours By Appointment","http://www.wfhb.org","Radio Station & Non-Profit");
        id=db.insertTitle("Brinegar Eye Care","4001 E. 3rd St. Suite 8 Bloomington, IN", "812-339-7995", "Mon-F:9AM-5PM","http://www.brinegareyecare.com","Optometrist");
        id=db.insertTitle("Sole Sensations","414 S. College Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-331-1962", "Mon:10AM-6PM Tues:10AM-8PM Wed:10AM-6PM Thurs:10AM-8PM Sat:10AM-5PM","http://www.solesensations.com/Soul-Inspirations.html","Orthotics & Shoes");
        id=db.insertTitle("Bloomignton Area Birth Services (BABS)","2458 S. Walnut St. Bloomington, IN", "812-337-8121", "Mon-Fri:10AM-5PM Sat:10AM-2PM" ,"http://www.bloomingtonbirth.org","Holistic and Naturopathic & Non-Profit & Gifts & Toys & Books & Maternity/Nursing Wear & Prenatal and Postnatal Yoga & Childbirth Classes & Breastfeeding Classes and Consultation");
        id=db.insertTitle("Karen Knight, LMHC Counseling Services","115 N. College Ave Suite 214 Bloomington, IN", "812-361-3601", "Mon-Fri:9AM-8PM By Appointment" ,"http://www.karenknight.net","Mental Health & Counseling");
        id=db.insertTitle("Mister Buck's Genuinely Good Pet Food Compnay","319 S. Mitchell Bloomington, IN", "812-384-3853", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.mrbuckspetfood.com","Pet Care");
        id=db.insertTitle("Center for Sustainable Living","323 S. Walnut St. Bloomington, IN", "812-332-8796", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.simplycsl.org","Non-Profit");
        id=db.insertTitle("Friends of Art Bookshop","1201 E. 7th St. (Fine Arts Building, Indiana University) Bloomington, IN", "812-855-7498","M-Thurs:9AM-6PM Sat-Sun:1PM-5PM" ,"http://www.fa.indiana.edu/foart/","Non-Profit & Books & Art Books & Textbooks");
        id=db.insertTitle("Cardinal Stage Company","900 S. Walnut St. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-3020", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.cardinalstage.org","Non-Profit & Theater");
        id=db.insertTitle("Bloomington Playwrights Project","107 W. 9th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-1188", "Mon-Fri:9AM-5PM" ,"http://www.newplays.org","Non-Profit");
        id=db.insertTitle("Boxcar Books","408 E. 6th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-8710", "Mon-Fri: 11AM-9PM Sat:10AM-9PM Sun:10AM-5PM" ,"http://www.boxcarbooks.org","Non-Profit & Books & Textbooks");
        id=db.insertTitle("Community Foundation of Bloomington and Monroe County,Inc.","101 W. Kirkwood Ave. Suite 321 Bloomington, IN", "812-333-9016", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.cfbmc.org","Non-Profit");
        id=db.insertTitle("Windfall Dancers","1101 N. Dunn St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-0506", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.windfalldancers.org","Non-Profit & Modern Dance & Dance");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Updraft Supplementary Scholarship Project, Inc. (USSP)","403 E. 6th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-961-3553 Toll Free:877-451-8535", "Mon-Fri:9AM-5PM" ,"http://www.usspkids.org","Non-Profit");
        id=db.insertTitle("Story Insights","P.O. Box 2264. Bloomington, IN 47402", "812-340-0479", "24hrs" ,"http://storyinsights.com","Non-Profit & Story Development & Project Management & Web Design");
        id=db.insertTitle("Middle Way House","P.O. Box 95 Bloomington, IN 47402", "Administration:812-333-7404 Crisis Line:812-336-9063", "24hr Internet Access" ,"http://www.middlewayhouse.org","Non-Profit");
        id=db.insertTitle("Baugh Enterprises, Inc","1611 S Rogers St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-8189", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.baughenterprises.com","Printing Service & Printwork Design");
        id=db.insertTitle("White Rabbit","118 W. 6th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-5020 Fax:812-339-7847", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.whiterabbitcopyservice.com","Printing Service");
        id=db.insertTitle("Mr. Copy","501 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-2679", "Mon-Fri:9AM-6PM Sat: Noon-5PM" ,"http://www.copysales.com","Printing Service & Graphic Design");
        id=db.insertTitle("Rosenplot Design","P.O Box 1083 Bloomington, IN 47402", "812-822-2077 Fax:812-822-2077", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.rosenplotdesign.com","Graphic Design");
        id=db.insertTitle("Patrick Siney Art Direction and Design","1303 S. Stull Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-334-0019", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.patricksiney.com","Graphic Design & Web Design");
        id=db.insertTitle("Bloomington Cooking School","115 N. College Ave. Suite 014 Bloomington, IN ", "812-333-7100", "Mon-Fri:8:30AM-5PM" ,"http://www.bloomingtoncookingschool.com","Cooking Class");


    }

    //private void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    //  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
    //  int length;
    //  while((length=inputStream.read(buffer))>0){
    //      outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
    //  }
    //  inputStream.close();
    //  outputStream.close();
    //}
```

}

after a few edits I am now getting errors that are shown in the logcat

```
    04-26 07:12:49.949: I/Process(18874): Sending signal. PID: 18874 SIG: 9
    04-26 07:12:54.070: D/dalvikvm(19443): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 2% free 10842K/11011K, paused 50ms, total 52ms
    04-26 07:12:54.070: I/dalvikvm-heap(19443): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.203MB for 614416-byte allocation
    04-26 07:12:54.220: D/dalvikvm(19443): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 11440K/11655K, paused 82ms+17ms, total 148ms
    04-26 07:12:54.280: D/dalvikvm(19443): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 11440K/11655K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
    04-26 07:12:54.300: I/dalvikvm-heap(19443): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.245MB for 1093136-byte allocation
    04-26 07:12:54.440: D/dalvikvm(19443): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 12508K/12743K, paused 74ms+15ms, total 141ms
    04-26 07:12:55.160: D/gralloc_goldfish(19443): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    04-26 07:13:00.769: D/AndroidRuntime(19443): Shutting down VM
    04-26 07:13:00.769: W/dalvikvm(19443): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at com.example.database.DBUse$2.onClick(DBUse.java:123)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-26 09:12:27.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3962):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not searching because you have only displayed messages on in your 'OnClickListener startName' - no actual code to search. You should call your 'search function' from inside the OnClickListener startName.

Comment: I added code to the onclick listeners and got errors. I posted my logcat above

Comment: try double click on one of the logcat lines
E/AndroidRuntime(1018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1018): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at com.example.database.DBUse$1.onClick(DBUse.java:87)
to see which line is causing the error. 
the field db is probably not initialised

Comment: the place it keeps taking me to is the    db.execSQL("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where name ="+"+dEdit+", null);
line of code how would I go about initializing it if that is the issue. I haven't had problems with a variable like that before since I use it in other areas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the database from inside your onClickListeners

```
private OnClickListener startName=new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View v){
            //Add code to read the contents of your name textbox and query the database
            Log.d(logtag,"onClick() called - stop button");
            Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v(logtag,"onClick() called - stop button");
        }

    };
        //Informs the user what is being searched
    private OnClickListener startType=new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View v){
            //Add code to read the contents of your type textbox and query the database
            Log.d(logtag,"onClick() called - stop button");
            Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(logtag,"onClick() called - stop button");
            }

    };
```

These onClickListeners are called when you click on the buttons to perform your search. Currently they are only displaying a Toast which tells you what you are searching but it is not actually performing a search.

**EDIT :**

Check if your variable **db** is Null in the onClickListeners

Also change the

db.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where name ="+dEdit, null)

to

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where name ="+dEdit.getText().toString(), null);

Now you can use the Cursor to read through the results

**EDIT 2 :**

Change for both the onClickListeners

Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where type like%"+"+dEdit.getText().toString()+%", null);

to

Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where type like%"+dEdit.getText().toString()+"%", null);

**EDIT 3 :**

In your class DBUse the variable name **MainActivity db = new...** is clashing with class variable **SqliteDatabase db**. Also in your onCLickListeners the object **db** has not been initialised and hence the null pointer exception.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I'm a little confused on the code necessary to do it. Would I need to do another db.execSQL(inside of this is the query code)?

Comment: I tried the suggestion of adding a query to the onclick listeners but it results in an error and the application to close

Comment: **db.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where name ="+dEdit, null);** Shouldn't you be doing dEdit.getText() in that statement

Comment: I just tried that and have edited the code above to show the logcat

Comment: How do I check to see if the variable db is null?

Comment: You have misplaced quotes in your **startType** onClickListener which is messing up everything. **db.rawQuery(""SELECT business,address...** quotes opened and closed before SELECT

Comment: If you are using eclipse then just add a breakpoint at the said line and watch the value of the variable.

Comment: what is the variable cur doing once it is used for the rawQuery? Eclipse keeps telling me that the value of cur is not being used.

Comment: The cursor stores the results returned by your query. You need to use the cursor to read the rows returned. Read the documentation on **android cursor**

Comment: Updated my code again to try and have cursor activity still errors when implemented. Updated code is above.